# Calculating with JSON array data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Stuck once again today, but i am trying to calculate with specific values from a JSON array. I can't seem to isolate the appropriate data. Can someone help me with this?

This is my JSON response:

```
[{"employee":[{"firstname":"Harry","birthdate":"1965-10-05","age":50}]},{"employee":[{"firstname":"Pete","birthdate":"1985-10-09","age":30}]}]
```

I'd like to get all the ages and add them for further use (for example average age). Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried.

Comment: Use [`JSON-parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse`) to create a real object, and then just get the values you need.

Comment: @Bart the structure of your data is quite deep for no apparent reason

Comment: @Saar, it's a requirement for the application i have to make...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example for you:

```
var jsonData = [{"employee":[{"firstname":"Harry","birthdate":"1965-10-05","age":50}]},{"employee":[{"firstname":"Pete","birthdate":"1985-10-09","age":30}]}];

var sumOfAges = 0;
for(var i = 0; i<jsonData.length; i++){
    sumOfAges += jsonData[i]["employee"][0].age;
}
console.log(sumOfAges);
var averageAge = sumOfAges / jsonData.length;
console.log(averageAge);
```

you can find the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/La9rzh8t/1/

Comment: Down voter, please give an explanation... this is redicules

Comment: Thanks Saar! This fixes it :) Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`JSON#parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) we can quite easily sum all ages of each employee in your data.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdgluck/6owo32b9/) which uses the below function:

```
function sumAllAges(data) {
    return data.reduce(function(total, obj) {
        total += obj.employee[0].age;
        return total;
    }, 0);
}
```